# Calculate 32 bit shift VHDL delay

Tags: vhdl, shift

[my wave form]
[1]
The shifter is a component which is able to implement both arithmetic and logical shift operations.
For this implementation you are not allowed to use shift operator.
AL input decides whether you have arithmetic or logic shift operation.
dir also decided the direction of your shift.
shifting input value also decides how many shifts you are expecting.
You can assume each single bit shifting takes 10 ns in shift component. For example if you have chosen shifting = 5 regardless of shift direction or type (arithmetic or logic), the delay of this component is 50 ns.

How to find out the delay? each bit has 10 ns delay, what should i do for 10* shifting delay?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY shifter IS
    GENERIC (BW : INTEGER :=32);
    PORT ( i : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 DOWNTO 0);
             dir : IN BIT; -- dir ='0' means shift right and dir ='1' means shift left
             AL: IN BIT ; -- Arithmetic or logical shift asume AL='1' means arithmetic an AL ='0' means logical
             shifting : IN INTEGER range 0 to BW -1;
             o: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 DOWNTO 0));
    END ;

ARCHITECTURE shifter_arch OF shifter IS

BEGIN 
process(dir,i,AL,shifting)
variable temp: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 begin
 if dir='0' then
    if AL='0' then
        temp:= i(BW-(1+shifting) downto 0)&(BW-1 downto BW-(1+shifting)=> '0');
    else
        temp:= i(BW-(1+shifting) downto 0)&(BW-1 downto BW-(1+shifting)=> i(BW-1));
    end if;

elsif dir ='1' then
    if AL='0' then
        temp:= i(BW-1 downto shifting)&((shifting-1) downto 0=> '0');
    else 
        temp:= i(BW-1 downto shifting)&((shifting-1) downto 0=> i(0));
    end if;

end if;
o <= temp ;
end process;
END shifter_arch ;
```

Comment: Your shifter  doesn't successfully analyze. The outer for generate loop depends on `shifting` as the right bound and shifting  is an input port (non static). IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.8 Generate statements "The discrete range in the generate parameter specification of a for generate statement shall be a static discrete range; similarly, each condition in an if generate statement shall be a static expression."  *Shall* (*must* -1993) has mandatory weight, and should have produced an error instead of failing to elaborate. Do you mean to use sequential loop statements (inside a process)?

Comment: what should i get the n bit shifting without the generate?

Comment: A for loop in a process?

Comment: if i cannot use the for loop, how should the shifting process? I need process at while loop.

Answer (score 0):

first: you write 10 ns but you take a photo by 1 ps step in your simulator,
and I can't Understand.
second: if you didn't succeed in ISim change your simulator to ModelSim and compile your code in Quartos  not in ISE and it's simulator. because they didn't support time's simulation better.